# How to handle right click event on nvd3 pie chart in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-nvd3 for graphs in my project.

Can any one help me that the how right click event works on nvd3 pie chart?

means when I click(right-click) the chord of the pie chart I want to show the particular list.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shows how you can bind on click events in a chart:

```
$scope.options = {
chart: {
//chart events
pie: {
  dispatch: {
      chartClick: function(e) {...},
      elementClick: function(e) {...},
      elementDblClick: function(e) {...},
      elementMouseover: function(e) {...},
      elementMouseout: function(e) {...}            
  }
},
}
}
```

inside the function you can use `e.value` and `e.point` as well to get the desired functionality.

Reference: https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/70

Comment: By this we can't handle RightCLick event. I want Right click function for nvd3 pie chart